# Como chamar uma function de outro arquivo, dentro de uma function do arquivo principal?

Tags: react

Tenho no arquivo **App.js**
E na primeira vez que é carregado, ele chama a `const response = await api.get('/searchDate');`, e retorna uma lista de `dates`. Quero pegar a primeira posição da lista, chamar o arquivo **Transaction.js** e buscar no back, as informações de acordo com o `date[0]`.

Teria como fazer isto?

**Observação:** Toda vez que uma nova `date` é selecionada o arquivo **Transaction.js** é chamado e envia o `dateSelected` e busca as informações. Com a chamada no `html` no `return` `<Transaction dateSelected={dateSelected} />`.

Porém, eu queria chama-lo a primeira vez que carrega a página, com a primeira `date` da lista.

**Arquivo App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);
  const [dateSelected, setDateSelected] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadDates(){
      const response = await api.get('/searchDate');
      setDates(response.data.yearMonth);
    };
    console.log(dates[0]); // aqui ele mostra certinho o date da primeira posição - ele seria o dateSelected
    // Como chamar o function Transaction({dateSelected}) {
    loadDates();
  },[dates[0]]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setDateSelected(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div id="app">
      <main>
        <Transaction dateSelected={dateSelected} />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Arquivo Transaction.js**

```
function Transaction({dateSelected}) {
  const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadTransaction() {
      const response = await api.get('/search?yearMonth='+dateSelected);
      setTransactions(response.data.transaction);
    };
    loadTransaction();
  }, [dateSelected]);
```

Comment: o componente precisa de um estado e esse estado controlar se é carregado 1 ou mais vezes! só isso acho que é o necessário, agora se está mudando é porque você no mesmo código muda o estado ou talvez pega um estado que esteja mudando e por isso do carregamento do arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix um demo no [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-oskar-zq7vs) que certamente não corresponde a funcionalidade que você quer, mas exemplifica como importar arquivos e extrair hooks.
Para reaproveitamento de código, use `import`. Você tipicamente importa funções, classes ou constantes.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import api from "../utils/fakeApi";
import Transaction from "./Transaction";
```

Para reaproveitamento de ciclo de vida, [crie hooks customizados](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html). Por convenção, um hook deve começar com `use` e ter um nome que começa com maiúsculo logo após.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import api from "../utils/fakeApi";

export default function useTransaction(dateSelected) {
  const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadTransaction() {
      const response = await api.get("/search?yearMonth=" + dateSelected);
      setTransactions(response.data.transaction);
    }
    loadTransaction();
  }, [dateSelected]);

  return transactions;
}
```

Não confunda hooks com componentes de UI. Estes retornam componentes e podem (ou não) usar hooks. Funções ou classes de UI devem começar com letra maiúscula.

```
import React from "react";
import useTransaction from "../hooks/useTransaction";

export default function Transaction({ dateSelected }) {
  const transactions = useTransaction(dateSelected);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>transactions</h2>

      <p>para {dateSelected.toDateString()}:</p>

      <ul>
        {transactions.map(item => (
          <li key={item}>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: entendi o que vc fez. Só tem uma coisa que preciso. 

No código vc começa com o ```const [dateSelected, setDateSelected] = useState(new Date());```

Porém, não posso começar com o ```new Date()```, preciso começar com o primeiro ```Date``` que vier da chamada do ```const response = await api.get("/searchDate");```. Como faria isso?

Comment: APIs possuem combinações dos estados: carregando vs não-carregando e sucesso vs erro; você deve lidar com as 4 possibilidades. Enriqueça o seu hook para retornar tudo isso. Ex: https://andrewstevens.dev/posts/useApi-react-hook/